# @Autowired does not work while migrating from Spring 3.1.9 to Spring 4.2.4. But works with Spring 3 and Java7

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, migration, version

I have been strugging with DI with @Autowired faced during runtime. Please see i do not face any issue during compile time. I have added the spring-beans, spring-context,spring-core jar with 4.2.4 version. The same code works well with Spring 3 and not with Spring 4. Any suggestions is highly appreciated. Suggestions like the configuration checks or maven dependencies would also help.

Sample code below

```
@Component
@Qualifier(Names.NAME2_1)
public class ClassA implements InterfaceA {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(Names.NAME2)
    private InterfaceB<Entity> variable1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The official Spring documentation says that it is best to make injects via setter.

```java
// Fields
    //
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    // Injects are here
    //
    @Autowired
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setPasswordEncoder(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }
```

Don't forget to add the latest dependencies from https://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: Hi Artur, this simply doesn't work in my scenario. Here the @Autowired is failing when placed on a interface. and there is many implementation of the same interface. So this means, i have many implementation classes for the same interface. Hope this gives some clarity to the question. Also in my example i have mentioned autowiring on a interface. and the code is complied using java8 and spring4.2.4.